# Are you allowed to have an alternate source for a script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is is possible to have an alternate source for a javascript in HTML5? For example, I am using jQuery, and have it locally. But an I allowed to include an `alt` attribute so that if that doesn't work, Google's jQuery will load?

If it works, the code would look something like this: `<script src="enter your text here.js" alt="googlescode"></script>`

Comment: There're many script loaders written in JavaScript. Shall we assume you want a static HTML solution?

Comment: Sure, but that is not what my question is about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is jQuery, you might want to look at [this article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx).

Snippet:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It works perfect, just curious to know if there is a workaround for CSS too?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do it. [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) has a good example for jQuery loading.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

But it uses it the other way around. If the script from google couldn't be loaded, it falls back to your local script.

You should load the CDN version as a first try anyway, as it loads quicker than a "local" version.

Comment: On my machine, I find that the local loads much faster.

Comment: If you load on localhost, it is of course faster, but not in a real production environment.. You can read this article which explains the benefits of it. http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Answer (score 3):

When implementing them I realized all the former answers have the common problem that Chrome will block them with slow connections since `document.write` is a **synchronous function**.
The issue is discussed in [this post](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write).

The solution usually is using a moderns loader, or pre-compiling the js code.

However, if your use-case still requires this approach, you need to use an async call. An illustrative example is [the way Google Analytics is loaded](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/#the_javascript_tracking_snippet).

Basically, the code above translates into:

```
    <script>window.jQuery || (function(){
        // Create the DOM node
        a=document.createElement('script');
        a.src="http://path-to-the-script.js";
        a.async=1;
        // Find a node, and insert the script before it
        m=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m);
    })()</script>
```