# Google Hosted Libraries will be not loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a strange problem. Libraries from Google Hosted Libraries will be not loaded. The HTML code ist pretty simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

It seems that something denieds the access to "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/..." on my system. At the network monitoring or even with Wireshark I don't see any try to load this library.

At first I thought Kasperski could forbid the access, but it also doesn't if I deactivate it.

If copy the url to my browser's addres bar, everything works fine.
If I change the URL to "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/..." in the HTML file, it works too.

Any ideas??

**Edit:**

**Thank you guys for your help!**

Comment: Are you accessing the HTML file via the filesystem or via a web server?

Comment: Any ideas- use http://

Comment: @scrowler Not required. If you omit the protocol from the URL the browser uses the protocol that was used to load the page.

Comment: Ya, but he said it worked for him so why waste any more time on it?

Comment: @scrowler — Because it stops working if the page gets loaded over HTTPS.

Comment: Tibos is hinting the right way. This does not work when you try it from the file system, as you are not having/implying any protocol then.

Comment: If you force `http:` in a page that is loaded with `https:` the browser will probably block the insecure content. That's why the protocol is omitted.

Comment: To expand @Tibos' comment: Do you access your HTML file with either `http` or `https` protocol? Only them will work with a protocol-relative link…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `//` at the start of the src loads the source over the protocol you used to access the page. If you access the page via HTTP, then it will be equivalent to `http://`, if you access it via HTTPS, it will be equivalent to `https://`. The problem comes if you access it via the filesystem, in which case it will look for the jQuery file on your file system (at that particular location) and obviously not find it.

The best solution varies, but i would recommend setting up a local webserver even for small projects.

Answer (score 0):

Check cross domain script loading.
Are you testing it on Localhost?

1. Some browsers will not connect to it if the html file is launched directly from your hard drive ('//:' will try to fetch file:// not http/https... i thhink :P )
2. Localhost settings (WAMP, XAMP etc. in default should let you fetch script from another domain)
3. Add a script to load from local folder if not available from Google cdn like here:

[another post about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677007/are-you-allowed-to-have-an-alternate-source-for-a-script)